# Alternate approach to reversing a list of lists?

Tags: python

Is there any alternate approach to flip the rows upside down in a list of lists. numpy or any other built in function are not needed here.

```
i = 0
n = len(image)
while i < (n // 2):
    image[i], image[n - 1 - i] = image[n - 1 - i], image[i]
    i += 1
return image
```

Here image is a list of lists.

Comment: What is ``image``?

Comment: image is a list of lists.

Comment: Welcole to SO, please always provide a data sample, please provide image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it couldn't be simpler:

```
image.reverse()
return image
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have

```
>>> image = [[1, 2, 3], [50, 60], [444], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

You can reverse the sub-lists by

```
>>> [lst[::-1] for lst in image]
[[3, 2, 1], [60, 50], [444], [10, 9, 8, 7]]
```

or if the outer image-list should be reversed too:

```
>>> [lst[::-1] for lst in image[::-1]]
[[10, 9, 8, 7], [444], [60, 50], [3, 2, 1]]
```

I hope this is what you want.